# Post to facebook after login fails Android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

In my `postToFacebook()` method. I checked if the user is connected if it is i post a link on my wall. When the user is not signed in, The facebook sdk login progress pop up and i login successfully using my credentials. My problem is after login i need to `postonWall` directly but the `postOnWall` is not posting to facebook.  If i am already login and i post, then it is posted. Any help please. Here is my full postToFacebook code.

```
public void postToFacebook(){


        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

        loginToFacebook();
    }



    /**
     * Function to login into facebook
     * */
    public void loginToFacebook() {

        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

            /*btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            // Making get profile button visible
            btnFbGetProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Making post to wall visible
            btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Making show access tokens button visible
            btnShowAccessTokens.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/

            new loadingTask().execute();

            System.out.println("one");
            Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
        }

        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(this,
                    new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                    new DialogListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // Function to handle cancel event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // Function to handle complete event
                            // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    facebook.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();

                            // Making Login button invisible
                            /*btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            // Making logout Button visible
                            btnFbGetProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            // Making post to wall visible
                            btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            // Making show access tokens button visible
                            btnShowAccessTokens.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/

                            new loadingTask().execute();



                            System.out.println("two");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError error) {
                            // Function to handle error

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                            // Function to handle Facebook errors

                        }

                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }



    /**
     * Function to show Access Tokens
     * */
    public void showAccessTokens() {
        String access_token = facebook.getAccessToken();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Access Token: " + access_token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    /**
     * Function to Logout user from Facebook
     * */
    public void logoutFromFacebook() {
        mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
                if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // make Login button visible
                            /*btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            // making all remaining buttons invisible
                            btnFbGetProfile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            btnShowAccessTokens.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);*/
                        }

                    });

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void postOWall(String msg) {

         Bundle params = new Bundle();
         params.putString("link", "http://google.com");

         mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new RequestListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("onComplete", "complete");
            }
            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                e.printStackTrace();

                Log.i("onComplete", "onIOException");

            }
            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("onComplete", "onFileNotFoundException");
            }
            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("onComplete", "onMalformedURLException");

            }
            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("onComplete", "onFacebookError");
            }

//        try {
//              // String response = facebook.request("me");
//               Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
//               //parameters.putString("caption", "Test Caption");   
//               parameters.putString("link", "http://www.google.com");
//              // parameters.putString("caption", "Test Caption: http://google.com/");
//              // parameters.putString("method", "stream.publish");
////               response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, 
////                       "POST");
//               //Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me", params, new UserRequestListener());
//              // Util.mAsyncRunner.request("me", parameters, new UserRequestListener());
//               mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST", new UserRequestListener(),null);
////               Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
////               if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
////                       response.equals("false")) {
////                  Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
////               }
//        } catch(Exception e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }

    }, params);

}

    public void postOnWall(String link) {
        try {
               String response = facebook.request("me");
               Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
               //parameters.putString("caption", "Test Caption");  
               System.out.println("response link: "+link);
               parameters.putString("link", link);
              // parameters.putString("caption", "Test Caption: http://google.com/");
              // parameters.putString("method", "stream.publish");
               response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, 
                       "POST");

                FacebookSuccessMessage.title="";
                FacebookSuccessMessage.mesg="PostÃ© sur Facebook";
                FacebookSuccessMessage.button_text="OK";

                Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);

                if (response!=null){
                    Intent i = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), FacebookSuccessMessage.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

               if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                       response.equals("false")) {
                  Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
               }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }


     class loadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void> {

          @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


             super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("response c : "+ constants);
             postOnWall(constants);

            return null;
        }


     }
```

Comment: Please use Facebook SDK 3.0+

Comment: facebook sdk 3.0+ ?" but what have i done wrong

Comment: The code may be correct, but as we know that Facebook object is depreciated in the new SDK and the Sessions are managed by a Session object. So potentially you are getting this error due to accessing the methods of a depreciated object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this code for posting with Facebook SDK 3.0 and this is working.

Reference the Facebook SDK 3.0 Library project in your current project.
Set the AppId in your String.xml file:

```
<string name="app_id">123456789012345</string>
```

After that add a MetaTag in your manifest file:

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

For Logging and and Logging out, you can simply use Facebook Login Button widget **"com.facebook.widget.LoginButton"**.

This widget manages the Sessions automatically, so you do-not have to worry about that.
Just place this button in the right place in your Layout.xml file.
Initialize this button like any other buttons:

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_ID);
```

After initializing, set permissions on the LoginButton

```
authButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_stream","read_stream"));
```

and implement setSessionStatusCallback method of the Login button widget:

```
authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() 
{
 public void call(Session session, SessionState state,Exception exception) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (session.isOpened()) 
    {
    Log.i(TAG, "Access Token" + session.getAccessToken());
    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,Response response) 
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (user != null) 
            {
            Log.i(TAG, "User ID " + user.getId());
            Log.i(TAG,"Email "+ user.asMap().get("email"));
            }
        }});
    } 
    else 
    {
    //This else condition will be executed when logout will be clicked.
    }
}
});
```

Below is the method for posting on Facebook.

```
private void publishStory(String status)
{       
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

if (session != null) 
    {
    Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
    postParams.putString("message", status);
    Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() 
        {
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e)
              {

              } 

        public void onIOException(IOException e) 
              {

              } 
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundExceptione) 
              {

              } 
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) 
              {

              }


    public void onCompleted(Response response) 
    {
        JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
        String postId = null;
        try 
        {
            postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            Log.i("JSON", "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
        }
        FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
        Log.e("post response", response.toString());
        if (error != null) 
        {
        } 
        else 
        {
        }
    }
};
Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
}
}
```

Comment: does it cater for authentication /

Comment: Umm, yes. The Session object checks for the active Sessions.
You can use the Facebook SDK 3.0 login button widget, which automatically manages the Sessions. I am updating my answer in few moments with login/logout management.

Comment: i implemented your method in my apps but it is not working. i have no post on my facebook wall

Comment: Ok, please share your feed back afterwards and do accept the answer.

Comment: in facebook 3.0 we dont need APP_ID and please can i get your demo ?

Comment: You don't need to provide an App_ID in the .java file, i have updated the answer. Please re-check it.

Comment: Thanks i am getting Redirect URL: fbconnect://success?error_code=901&error_message=This+app+is+in+sandbox+mode.++Edit+the+app+configuration+at+http%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fapps+to+make+the+app+publicly+visible. Should not pass a read permission (read_stream) to a request for publish or manage authorization in my log

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33589/discussion-between-dimitri-and-salman-khakwani)