# Android - Facebook log in and Sign up

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Hello I'm creating an app that there is a log in and sign up screen. In the sign up if a user sign's in using Facebook, and later log of - he will go to log in screen. There is a log in using Facebook button, and when a user tries to log in, Facebook gives me an error and Okay button. I think this is because the user already has given the app permissions(or something like that). Now my question is how can I create the log in function if a user has already signed in using Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

For Login/Logout purpose you can use Facebook SDK 3.0, it uses information from Facebook App on Android (if it is installed), so if the user has already signed in using the Facebook App, then the user would not have to sign-in again, the SDK will simply fetch the current Session.
I have answered the detailed implementation for this on the link below:
[Post to facebook after login fails Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683338/post-to-facebook-after-login-fails-android/17684571#17684571)
Thanks.