# Error: The page you requested can not be displayed right now

Tags: android

Integrated facebook sdk 2.3 to android app here after entering the credentials getting the above error.here i am placing the login() code.suggest me suitable solution.This is login method.

```
public void loginToFacebook() {

        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

            btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            // Making get profile button visible
            btnFbGetProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Making post to wall visible
            btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
        }

        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(AndroidFacebookConnectActivity.this,
                    new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                    new DialogListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    facebook.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

and this is exact error [image: RClick and view image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a depreciated SDK, my friend. Therefore, it's difficult to judge that the error is either with your code or from Facebook.
I recommend you to use Facebook SDK 3.0 or above. In Facebook SDK 3.0 the Sessions are automatically managed by the Session object and User Logins are also handled by the default Facebook's Login widget. So you don't have to worry about implementing the login/log-out flow by yourself.
I have answered this question before, you can find the details regarding Login/Logout using Facebook SDK 3.0 in the **[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683338/post-to-facebook-after-login-fails-android/17684571#17684571)** link
For further information regarding latest Facebook SDKs, you can also visit https://developers.facebook.com/android/

**EDIT:**
Please check **[this](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/03/android-login-using-facebook-sdk-30.html)** tutorial for Facebook 3.0 SDK integration in Android Application.

Comment: felt difficult with developers page ,could you plz recommend easy tutorial links.

Comment: how to set up the logout button

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35710/discussion-between-prabha-and-salman-khakwani)

Comment: Hi, sory for late reply. I just woke up.