# Post on FB wall Using 3.0 SDK

Tags: android, facebook, session

Hello fellow programmers, I having difficulties on the new Facebook SDK,

Scenario is:

im using fragment so I follow this steps

[Why doesn't Android Facebook interface work with Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943392/why-doesnt-android-facebook-interface-work-with-fragments/10964421#comment17300713_10964421)

and now Im getting the oncomplete and the token ID

Now I want to post on my wall so ive created this function

```
private void publishStory(Session session) {

    if (session != null){

        // Check for publish permissions    
        session.addCallback(new StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
                List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays
                    .asList("publish_actions");
                session
                    .requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                        getActivity(), PERMISSIONS));

                Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(
                    session, "Temple Hello Word Sample",
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            Log.i("fb:done = ", response.getGraphObject() + ","
                                + response.getError());
                        }
                    });
                request.executeAsync();

            }

        });
```

And put the Declaration on the Oncomplete

```
    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {



                                                        publishStory(session);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.v("FACEBOOK ", "NO ACCESS");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

My problem is on this line of code `session.addCallback(new StatusCallback() {` it skips the next step thus ending the function without posting on my wall.

I am quite sure that the session is active as I have applicationID and access token..

Any Help?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Im using this code based on the Answer below and added new permissions

```
private void publishStoryTEST(final Session session)
{       

    if (session != null) 
    {
        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("message", "TEST");
        Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() 
        {


            public void onCompleted(Response response) 
            {


                JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                String postId = null;
                try 
                {
                    postId = graphResponse.getString("id");

                } 
                catch (JSONException e) 
                {
                    Log.i("JSON", "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                }
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                Log.e("post response", response.toString());
                if (error != null) 
                {
                } 
                else 
                {
                }

            }
        };
        List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays
                .asList("publish_actions");
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(getActivity(), PERMISSIONS));    
        Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();

    }
}
```

But still Im getting an error saying

```
The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

Why is that I still get that error? Does the permission never called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is common, i am sharing with you the working source code of the Posting Method that i am currently using in my Application.

```
private void publishStory(String status)
{       
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

if (session != null) 
{
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("message", status);
Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() 
    {
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e)
          {

          } 
    public void onIOException(IOException e) 
          {

          } 
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundExceptione) 
          {

          } 
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) 
          {

          }

public void onCompleted(Response response) 
{
    JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
    String postId = null;
    try 
    {
        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
    } 
    catch (JSONException e) 
    {
        Log.i("JSON", "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
    }
    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
    Log.e("post response", response.toString());
    if (error != null) 
    {
    } 
    else 
    {
    }
}
};

Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
}
}
```

I hope this solves your problem.

**EDIT:**
Please refer to the following links, for a detailed procedure of setting up Facebook SDK 3.0 with proper permissions and posting features.
[Post to facebook after login fails Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683338/post-to-facebook-after-login-fails-android/17684571#17684571)
http://www.kpbird.com/2013/03/android-login-using-facebook-sdk-30.html

Comment: Still aint working and im getting an error on this line JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();

Comment: is it ok that I skip Request.Callback then after that the last step is onComplete?

Comment: im getting an error saying The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Comment: I think, you have not provided specific permissions for posting on Facebook. Please see the updated answer, thanks.

Comment: is there any way that I could do it on code behind? I am not using Login Button

Comment: According to Facebook Developer site, you should use a Login Button widget for Login and Logout purposes. Along with that, you should not skip the Request Callback part.

Comment: Although, if you want to manually handle the login logout stuff. Then i will suggest you to use `Session` object and put checks on `Session` object for checking the users current status and End or Establish new `Sessions` on Logout/Login events respectively.

Answer (score 1):

// Try below code

```
private void postData() {
        lnrPbr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        isSharingData = true;

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {

            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
            postParams.putString("name", getIntent().getStringExtra("IN_SHARE_CAPTION") == null ? "" : getIntent().getStringExtra("IN_SHARE_CAPTION"));
            postParams.putString("caption", getIntent().getStringExtra("IN_SHARE_CAPTION") == null ? "" : getIntent().getStringExtra("IN_SHARE_CAPTION"));
            postParams.putString("description", getIntent().getStringExtra("IN_SHARE_DESCRIPTION") == null ? "" : getIntent().getStringExtra("IN_SHARE_DESCRIPTION"));
            postParams.putString("link", getIntent().getStringExtra("IN_SHARE_SHARELINK") == null ? "" : getIntent().getStringExtra("IN_SHARE_SHARELINK"));
            postParams.putString("picture", getIntent().getStringExtra("IN_SHARE_THUMB") == null ? "" : getIntent().getStringExtra("IN_SHARE_THUMB"));
            postParams.putString("message", getIntent().getStringExtra("IN_SHARE_MESSAGE") == null ? "" : getIntent().getStringExtra("IN_SHARE_MESSAGE"));

            Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {

                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    isSharingData = false;
                    lnrPbr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        IjoomerUtilities.getCustomOkDialog(getString(R.string.facebook_share_title), error.getErrorMessage(), getString(R.string.ok), R.layout.ijoomer_ok_dialog, new CustomAlertNeutral() {

                            @Override
                            public void NeutralMethod() {
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        IjoomerUtilities.getCustomOkDialog(getString(R.string.facebook_share_title), getString(R.string.facebook_share_success), getString(R.string.ok), R.layout.ijoomer_ok_dialog, new CustomAlertNeutral() {

                            @Override
                            public void NeutralMethod() {
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };

            Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this tutorial..

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

```
public void postToWall() {
    // post on user's wall.
    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: The tutorial and your answer both are using depreciated Facebook object.

Comment: @Hari I cant use that as it was depreciated