# New (but different) Facebook ApplicationId causing NPE

Tags: java, android, facebook, authentication, nullpointerexception

At the below link, I had an issue with the Facebook SDK for Android crashing immediately upon opening the app. Someone was kind enough to help me fix my issue to a point that the activity is now displayed on the screen with the Facebook Log In button, but upon clicking the button, crashes.

[First post regarding this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346422/facebook-android-sdk-applicationid-causing-npe?noredirect=1)

The LogCat for this error is very similar to my errors from the original article, with the same null pointer exception error as before ('applicationId' cannot be null). What is going on? I quickly exhausted the small supply of resources dealing with this kind of issue, and if I am reading the LogCat correctly, none of the errors point to my code as causing a problem. I am new to Java so please be thorough if you know what is going on.

Manifest meta-data:

```
        <meta-data 
        android:name="com.facebook.skd.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />`
```

Strings.xml excerpt, censored with zero's:

```
<string name="app_id">000000000000000</string>
```

[LoginActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/fzb0waRv)

[MainActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/Y15ppcAC)

[Related LogCat](http://pastebin.com/7xiQBYrv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the spelling:

SDK, not SKD on ´com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId´

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />
```